# How do I compress/zip files in Bridge?

Tags: compression, adobe-bridge

I use Bridge for my workflow but I always have to  <kbd>right click > Reveal in Finder</kbd> to zip a folder. There is no option to do so when I right click in Bridge, as there is in the Finder window. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not missing something. The OS (Mac or Windows) can create zip files on the fly, so I guess it's never been something the Bridge team felt it would be redundant to add that to Bridge.

Comment: Except the whole premise of bridges is to replace finder.